# Display maximum n element of same size equally in a row with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to display a maximum of a certain amount, e.g. 3, of elements (e.g. `div` elements) in a row and all these elements should always have the same width towards each other but the width should still be flexible when resizing. The order of the elements should be from left to right. I want to use Flexbox.

For example, I want to display a maximum of 3 elements in a row, and if I have 4 elements, then the first 3 elements will be displayed in a row from left to right. The fourth element is in the second row at the very left.

The best I could do was this
https://jsfiddle.net/r6f5Ltag/3/

```
.flex-row-container {
    background: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-row-container > .flex-row-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
    height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.flex-row-item {
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
}
```

But as you can see the elements are centered and the width towards each other don't always stay the same towards each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is everything that you need. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nemanjaglumac/72y6kfrg/1/

No need for nesting of selecting the class with `>` selector.

```
.flex-row-container {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
  width: calc((100%/3) - 2px); /* divide by the number of elements and substract the width od the borders */

  &:last-child {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
}
```

P.S. Keep in mind that this is SCSS syntax (nesting with `&`). That will output as `.flex-row-item:last-child {...}`

EDIT: Actually, `flex-grow` is redundant in this particular example. Because, we are already defining the width of those elements. So, bottom line, you can write it even shorter as:

```
.flex-row-container {
  background: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row-item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
  width: calc((100%/3) - 2px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume there is no `column` property, where you set the number of columns for the elements to be placed in?

Comment: You can do it within the calc for width. For example, if you want 4 columns, calc would be `((100%/4) - 3px)`. Btw, I have updated an answer for even shorter solution.

Comment: If you know Sass, you can probably make a function or even a mixin (really depend on how you intend to use it), but basically the width is calculated with this formula `width: calc((100% / n) - (n-1)*$border-width)` where n is the number of columns/elements in a row.

Comment: We don't use Sass/scss

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the same width and still flexible you should select percent for the width. so instead of "max-width: 200px;" use "max-width: 33%" and if you want the fourth box in the second row start from left so you can set : "justify-content: flex-start;"

```
  .flex-row-container {
    background: #aaa;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .flex-row-container > .flex-row-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 33%;
  }

  .flex-row-item {
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    border: 1px solid #f76707;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making your code more cleaner and easy to read.

**.css**

```
.flex-row-container {
    background: whitesmoke;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-row-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  border: 1px solid #f76707;
  width: calc((100%/3) - 2px); 
}

.flex-row-item:last-child() {
    flex-grow: 0;
 }
```

In this part `width: calc((100%/3) - 2px);` it's to remove some strange margin can be adding.

I'll recommend you use the sass or scss syntax to handle such this.

Answer (score 0):

## Basically here is the general answer:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Change width: `calc(100% / 3);` if you want to change amount of items in a row (e.g. 3 is current item count). Add `flex-grow: 1;` to make items expand to borders (only if a row has less items than it supposes to have).